# Optionally calling a block in ruby

Tags: ruby

I have two ways I might need to call some code using a block.

Option 1:

```
foo()
```

Option 2:

```
block_function do 
  foo()
end
```

How do I switch between the two of these at runtime? I really don't want to do the following, because `foo()` is actually a whole lot of code:

```
if condition then
    foo()
else
    block_function do 
      foo()
    end
end
```

Comment: So move the large amount of code into its own method so that the option you outline isn't unpalatable?

Comment: Or if foo is using a bunch of local variables, you could define foo as a lambda.

Comment: What does `block_function`? or do you want to call `foo` with and without block? The you may use `block_given?` to check if a block is given to `foo`. (If this is meant, I can post a more detailed answer.

Comment: @knut, block_function is actually a `div do` call using Erector for Rails views. I want to optionally wrap a div around a block of view code. Basically, I can't change `block_function`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
def condition_or_block_function
  if condition
    yield
  else
    block_function { yield }
  end
end

condition_or_block_function do
  foo() # which is really a lot of code :)
end
```

Or as others suggested, make the `foo()` bunch of code an actual method and write what you wrote in the OP.

More generic version as @tadman suggests:

```
def condition_or_block condition, block_method, *args
  if condition
    yield
  else
    send(block_method, *args) { yield }
  end
end

condition_or_block(some_condition, some_block_yielding_method) do
  foo() # which is really a lot of code :)
end
```

@Christian Oudard added a comment specifying the specific problem, optionally decorating a code block with div do...end with Erector.  This suggests another approach:

```
class BlockWrapper
  def initialize(method=nil)
    @method = method
  end
  def decorate
    @method ? send(method) { yield } : yield
  end
end

wrapper = BlockWrapper.new( condition ? nil : :div )

wrapper.decorate do
  #code block
end
```

Comment: This could be genericized to take a method name to call if required.